# Maps and legal mention

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, mkmapview

With iOS < 6.0 we were able to re-position the "Google" link over map view (by browsing the subviews of map view). Now with iO6, there's a "legal" link and this is a MKAttributeLabel. A private class that we can't manipulate ...

My problem is that I must add a footer subview to my map and it'll hide the legal link ...
How can I solve this problem without any App Store rejection ?

Can I create another legal button my self and add it where I want in my map view ?
I have no idea what I'm able to do...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal advice, not programming advice.

Comment: Question is NOT actually about legal advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the footer view have to be inside the map boundary, why not put the map and the footer into the same super view?

Comment: Sorry this is what i've done. Footer and Map are subviews of one superview. The footer has transparency and is overlaying the map

Comment: Well if the problem is that it hides the map, don't make them overlap

Comment: Problem solved : I'm now using Route-Me and Bing map. Sorry Apple but upgrade your API ...

Comment: @Pierre Just curious: are you using Google API and Apple Map in your case? I am asking because one is not supposed to draw data gathered from Google over a map that is not Google Map. Are you saying that even though you are using Apple Map, you are still supposed to show the Google Legal link?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few answers recommending you move the legal label in the `viewDidAppear` of your view controller, however this doesn't work if you then resize your map view (like I am).

The best way is to subclass the `MKMapView` and override the `layoutSubviews` method. In my example I just needed to nudge the legal label above a semi-transparent toolbar.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    UILabel *legalLabel;
    for(UIView *view in self.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            legalLabel = (UILabel *)view;
            break;
        }
    }
    legalLabel.center = CGPointMake(legalLabel.center.x, self.bounds.size.height - 55.0f);
}
```

Comment: bad idea because you're dependant on every change about iOS.