# Move legal button on maps (iOS 6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maps and legal mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891373/maps-and-legal-mention)

In iOS 5 or lower I was able to move the Google logo in the map view. iO6 has a "legal" button and this is a MKAttributeLabel. MKAttributeLabel is a private class that I can't edit.
I have buttons which overlap the map in the bottom (by design) so i moved the google logo.

Is there a way to reposition the Legal button in ios6 maps?

Comment: the question for which this was marked as duplicate, did not really answer the question

Comment: Yes, i have checked, and concluded that it was closed for wrong reasons. But the solution is more complex when you rotate the  map, via a transformation matrix. I would like to add the label to my own view, which looses the Web link.

Comment: How is this a possible Duplicate if the question which linkes to my question is asked later?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The legal label is a standard UILabel, so you can change the frame like an other label :

```
UIView *legalView = nil;

for (UIView *subview in self.mapview.subviews) {
   if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            legalView = subview;
            break;
     }
}
legalView.frame = CGRectMake(150, 150, legalView.frame.size.width, legalView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: after "legalView = subview;" line, a "break;" would be nice.

Comment: This does not work well when an rotation marix is applied. It seems that addionally the anchor point of the legalView must be set, not only the frame

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working on iOS 7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201670/how-do-you-move-the-legal-sign-in-mapview/23913585#23913585 Check this