# IOS Map Legal Text change position vs Map Rotation

Tags: ios, iphone, text, dictionary, rotation

I'm using the answer os [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362850/move-legal-button-on-maps-ios-6) to change Map Legal Text position on the screen (Put it on the up right corner of the screen). 
Its works fine, but when the map is rotated, it fails.

I tried to insert the code in the following method to get the end of the rotation:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didChangeUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode animated:(BOOL)animated
```

But the legal text returns to its original position (bottom left corner).

How do I move the legal text again after the rotation ending?

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidAppear add following to change the legal label position

`UILabel *attributionLabel = [mapView.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
attributionLabel.center = CGPointMake(attributionLabel.center.x, attributionLabel.center.y - 44.0f);`

or another solution use topLayoutGuide and bottomLayoutGuide

.h

`@interface MapLayoutGuide : NSObject <UILayoutSupport>
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat aaLength;
- (id)initWithLength:(CGFloat)length;
@end`

.m

`@implementation MapLayoutGuide
- (id)initWithLength:(CGFloat)length {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _aaLength = length;
    }
    return self;
}
- (CGFloat)length {
    return _aaLength;
}
@end`

Usage:

`- (id<UILayoutSupport>)topLayoutGuide {
    return [[MapLayoutGuide alloc]initWithLength:44];
}
- (id<UILayoutSupport>)bottomLayoutGuide {
    return [[MapLayoutGuide alloc]initWithLength:44];
}`

Comment: Didn't work. Still the same problem of the post a mentioned in my question. The legal text keep returning to the original position (bottom left corner of the screen). Tks anyway.